# Google Fitness API in php

Tags: php, laravel, google-api, google-api-php-client, google-fit

```
     $user = Socialite::driver('google')->user();

        // Set token for the Google API PHP Client
        $google_client_token = [
            'access_token' => $user->token,
            'refresh_token' => $user->refreshToken,
            'expires_in' => $user->expiresIn
        ];

        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->setApplicationName("Laravel");
        $client->setDeveloperKey(env('GOOGLE_SERVER_KEY'));
        $client->setAccessToken(json_encode($google_client_token));
        $client->setScopes(Google_Service_Fitness::FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ);

        $fitness_service = new Google_Service_Fitness($client);

        $dataSources = $fitness_service->users_dataSources;
        $dataSets = $fitness_service->users_dataSources_datasets;

        $listDataSources = $dataSources->listUsersDataSources("me");


        dd($dataSets);
```

I tried this but it always ended giving me 
 "domain": "global",
    "reason": "insufficientPermissions",
    "message": "Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes."

Answer (score 0):

[Users.dataSources: list](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/reference/users/dataSources/list)  requires one of the following scopes to use.

[image]

You appear to be using one of the ones on the list

> Google_Service_Fitness::FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ

And i have tested it that scope does allow a call to that api which means its not an issue with the API.

The problem is that you have probably authenticated the user then changed the scope in your code and not reauthenticated the user requesting the new scope.  You need to login the user again

> 'approval_prompt' => 'force'

You need it to pop up and ask for the permission again

[image]

You may have to go to your google account and remove the apps permissions to reset it [remove](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3466521?hl=en)

Comment: 'approval_prompt' => 'force'
Where to add this??

Comment: I am trying since last 72 hours but not getting any way out for the same . Please let me know how to fix this .

Comment: Is it showing the screen requesting permissions again?

Comment: No its is not I ma not getting any screen requesting permission for a service

Comment: I cant see anything

Comment: Then you havent added force prompt or deleted your application from the users google account permissions.

Comment: It is working for people api but not working for fitness api